# Update only a table, but the table is associated with another

Tags: cakephp, updates

I have a main table, Cliente. This table are associated with another 20 tables. I´m trying update only the table Clientee using the code below:

```
$this->Cliente->updateAll(array("ec_cnpj" => $this->request->data['Cliente']['ec_cnpj'],
                                  "ec_cpf" => $this->request->data['Cliente']['ec_cpf'],
                                  "ec_rg" => $this->request->data['Cliente']['ec_rg'],
                                  "ec_rg_org_emissor" => $this->request->data['Cliente']['ec_rg'],
                                  "ec_rg_est_emissor" => $this->request->data['Cliente']['ec_rg_est_emissor'],
                                  "ec_nire" => $this->request->data['Cliente']['ec_nire']),
                            array("ec_codigo"=>$this->request->data['ec_codigo']))
```

But, Cake is generating a query to update all tables. How can I do to update only cliente table?

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

> By default, updateAll() will automatically join any belongsTo
>   association for databases that support joins. To prevent this,
>   temporarily unbind the associations.

So, [unbind](http://griffinm.wordpress.com/2007/06/15/using-unbindmodel-in-cakephp/) the correspondent models like

```
$this->Cliente->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('table1', 'table2')));
```

Read "[Creating and Destroying Associations on the Fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)" to have a better understanding of it.

Maybe you'll find something like [this](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20141224204902/http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cornernote/2006/12/10/unbindall) useful, but that escapes from what comes directly from cakephp, you'll have to create a new function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Worked very well!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Can you update the last [link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cornernote/2006/12/10/unbindall), it seems dead